# How to ensure that one coroutine completes before another is run?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have two coroutines. One has several coroutines with it. The first coroutine does not wait for the second to complete before the second one runs within the `Start()` method. Please see the code below.

```cs
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(DrawLineWithDuration (3.0f));
    StartCoroutine (changeLinePos (2.0f));
}

IEnumerator DrawLineWithDuration (float duration)  {

    lr.positionCount = 1;
    lr.SetPosition(0, GetPoint(0));

    float waitDur = duration / numPoints;

    for (int i = 1; i < numPoints + 1; i++) {
        float t = i / (float)numPoints;
        lr.positionCount = i+1;
        lr.SetPosition(i, GetPoint(t));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitDur);
    }
}

IEnumerator moveToPosition1(Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{

    float counter = 0;

    Vector3 startPos = points[1];

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        points[1] = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }

}

IEnumerator moveToPosition2(Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;
    Vector3 startPos = points[2];

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        points[2] = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}


IEnumerator moveToOriginal1(Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{

    float counter = 0;

    Vector3 startPos = points[1];

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        points[1] = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }

}

IEnumerator moveToOriginal2(Vector3 toPosition, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;
    Vector3 startPos = points[2];

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        points[2] = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}


IEnumerator changeLinePos(float waitTime)   {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

    while (isRepeating) {
        StartCoroutine (moveToPosition1 (newPos1, moveDuration));
        StartCoroutine (moveToPosition2 (newPos2, moveDuration));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (betweenPosMoveDelay);

        StartCoroutine (moveToOriginal1 (oriPos1, moveDuration));
        StartCoroutine (moveToOriginal2 (oriPos2, moveDuration));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (betweenPosMoveDelay);
    }

}
```

Within `Start()` how can I make sure that `StartCoroutine(DrawLineWithDuration (3.0f));` completes with its given duration before `StartCoroutine (changeLinePos (2.0f));` begins. Also within `changeLinePos(float waitTime)` how can I make sure that `moveToPosition1` and `moveToPosition2` complete before `moveToOriginal1` and `moveToOriginal1` and `moveToOriginal2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple, you can `yield return StartCoroutine(DrawLineWithDuration (3.0f));` as the first line in `changeLinePos`, like this:

```cs
void Start() {    
    StartCoroutine (ChangeLinePos (2.0f));
}

IEnumerator ChangeLinePos(float waitTime)   {
    yield return StartCoroutine(DrawLineWithDuration (3.0f));
    while (isRepeating) {
        StartCoroutine (MoveToOriginal1 (oriPos1, moveDuration));
        StartCoroutine (MoveToOriginal2 (oriPos2, moveDuration));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (betweenPosMoveDelay);
    }
}

IEnumerator MoveToOriginal1(Vector3 toPosition, float duration) {
    yield return StartCoroutine (MoveToPosition1 (newPos1, moveDuration));
    //Rest of MoveToOriginal1 code
}

IEnumerator MoveToOriginal2(Vector3 toPosition, float duration) {
    yield return StartCoroutine (MoveToPosition2 (newPos2, moveDuration));
    //Rest of MoveToOriginal1 code
}
```

With this structure, the timing is the following:

- `ChangeLinePos` starts in `Start()`
- The first line starts `DrawLineWithDuration` and stops the execution of `ChangeLinePos` until the former is finished
- When `DrawLineWithDuration` is finished, and if `isRepeating==true`, the code starts `MoveToOriginal1` and `MoveToOriginal2` synchronously
- `MoveToOriginal1` and `MoveToOriginal2` both start `MoveToPosition1` and `MoveToPosition2` and wait until the last two are finished.

I left the `while` because it seems to be affected by something outside the coroutines, so be sure that `isRepeating` changes to `false` when needed, if not the `MoveToOriginal1` and `MoveToOriginal2` coroutines will be started always until the application is stopped.